# ILogger Add Properties not within MessageTemplate (Serilog)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, blazor, serilog

I am running a Blazor WASM Hosted application using Serilog.Sinks.BrowserHttp on the Client and Serilog.AspNetCore.Ingestion and Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer on the Server.

My Server Program.cs is setup as follows

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("InstanceId", Guid.NewGuid())
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Origin", "Server")
                .CreateLogger();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("Starting up");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

My Server Startup.cs Configure is setup as follows

```
app.UseSerilogIngestion();
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
```

My Client Program.cs is setup as follows

```
//Serilog 
            var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();         
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
                .Enrich.WithProperty("InstanceId", Guid.NewGuid())
                .WriteTo.BrowserHttp(controlLevelSwitch: levelSwitch)
                .CreateLogger();
            

            Log.Information("Client has started");

            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddLogging(logging =>
           {
               logging.ClearProviders();
               logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
           });
```

This allows me to use dependency injection on my components and log as expected.  However, id like to add additional properties like Username, UserId etc outside of the MessageTemplate.   Example :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[Inject]
public ILogger<CountryList> Logger { get; set; }

Logger.LogError(ex, "An Exception was thrown", Username, UserId);
```

The ILogger is from the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging library which does not have .ForContext().  Is there a way to add properties besides the .BeginScope approach?  I really would like to keep it clean and single line as opposed to wrapping every logging with a using statement.

Comment: `BeginScope` is analogous to `ForContext`... How do you envisage adding the properties without either of these?

Comment: I was hoping possibly a Dictionary<string, object> that can be passed in the the Logger.Logxx() after the message template members that can be parsed and assigned to the variables within the log.  This way I dont have to add the properties I want logged within the MessageTemplate and making it harder to read